# Ruby HTTPclient: A relative URI in location header which is not recommended

Tags: ruby, httpclient

I want to scrape a website like this:

```
 url = 'https://www.example.com/projects/search?scope=projects'
 content = @clnt.get_content(url,nil,CONF.header)
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
```

But I get the following message:

```
/projects/search?scope=projects: a relative URI in location header which is not recommended
'The field value consists of a single absolute URI' in HTTP spec
Cookie#domain returns dot-less domain name now. Use Cookie#dot_domain if you need "." at the beginning.
```

Does anyone know how to handle it?

Comment: What line exactly causes that message? What is `@clnt`? What does the `get_content` method look like? What is `CONF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I read the implementation `get_content` works like `get` but also is allowed to follow redirects. The redirect in this case is done via an relative URL thus the gem yields the warning(s). [See the source code](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/blob/master/lib/httpclient.rb#L725)